# Is it possible to use sed instead of Grep -oP to extract a word?

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of data from an API that I'm trying to extract the words "cloudy" or rainy", I've used grep -oP, but was wondering if it's possible to use sed for it.

My code:

```
 grep "symbol id=" | grep -oP '(?<=code=").*?(?=")'
```

The API data:

```
<time datatype="forecast" from="2022-12-07T12:00:00Z" to="2022-12-07T13:00:00Z">
  <location altitude="585" latitude="60.8941" longitude="10.5001">
    <precipitation unit="mm" value="0.0" minvalue="0.0" maxvalue="0.0">. 
</precipitation>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
  </location>
</time>
    <symbol id="Cloud" number="4" code="cloudy"></symbol>
--
<time datatype="forecast" from="2022-12-07T12:00:00Z" to="2022-12-07T18:00:00Z">
  <location altitude="585" latitude="60.8941" longitude="10.5001">
    <precipitation unit="mm" value="0.0" minvalue="0.0" maxvalue="0.0">. 
 </precipitation>
    <minTemperature id="TTT" unit="celsius" value="-9.8"></minTemperature>
    <maxTemperature id="TTT" unit="celsius" value="-7.6"></maxTemperature>
    <symbol id="PartlyCloud" number="3" code="partlycloudy_day"></symbol>
  </location>
 </time>
```

Comment: Why not parse the XML instead? This is an XY problem.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `sed -n '/symbol id=/s/.*code="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'`

Comment: Please post valid XML.

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).